# Inconsistent Performance issues with Cosmos DB (Shared RU or Pr. Collection RU)

Tags: database, performance, request, azure-cosmosdb, units-of-measurement

Im experiencing inconsistent performance behaviors with Cosmos DB

I have a Cosmos DB Database, where i provisioned 20.000 RU at Database Level. 
I then add a Collection that is Shared among the 20.000 RU. (This is the only collection in the database at this point) I get throttled when trying to insert 20.000 Docs.
If i insert 20.000 Documents, in batches of 100 Documents at 10 Batches pr Call using Table API, i get throttled.

If I cretae a new Collection, where i provision 20.000 RU and run he exact same code, it works fine.

Questions
1: I would tink that 20.000 RU is the same whether comming from a Database with Shared RU, or provisoned on the collection lvl?
2: What if i have a database with 20.000 RU, and have 1000 Shared collctions, and 1 of these colletions requires 15.000 RU, the rest requires almost nothing?

Regards
Anders

Comment: This is an example of a document im trying to insert

Comment: public string DisplayName
public DateTime? TaskStartTime
public DateTime? TaskFinishTime
public string Duration
public string JobId
public string TaskId 
public string PoolId
public string NodeId
public TaskStatus Status
public string MaxTaskWallClockTime
public string MaxTaskRetryCount
public int? ExitCode
public int? RetryCount
public int? RequeueCount

Comment: You might see better luck with AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com for this question since there is subjectivity to it.

That said, how are you doing your inserts? If you try to insert all the items in order by partition key, your partition key itself will get throttled (a given partition key has some percentage of throughput available to it). If you insert in a more distributed pattern, you'll be able to use all your throughput. See this article to understand some of those concepts deeper: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data